# How to pass in list input into function for traversing tree?

Tags: python, tree

I am writing some code for traversing a tree:

```
root = [1, None, 2, 3]
class Treenode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def post_order_traversal_iterative(self,root):
        stack = [root]
        output = []
        if not root:
            return []
        while stack:
            curr = stack.pop()
            output.append(curr.val)
            if curr.right:
                stack.append(curr.right)
            if curr.left:
                stack.append(curr.left)
        return output

x = Solution()
print(Solution.post_order_traversal_iterative(x,root))
```

But I am getting the error that a 'list object has no attribute val'- which I totally get, but then how do I pass in my list as the input??

Comment: Where you create the `Treenode` instance? Also `post_order_traversal_iterative` is a method of `Solution` so you should call it in the following way: `x.post_order_traversal_iterative(root)`

Comment: Okay, I understand- thanks

Comment: @dhuishdiuhe Also to add on, when you write `stack = [root]`, stack will be a list of list which is not you want, It should just be `stack = root`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `post_order_traversal_iterative` expects a `Treenode` instance but you're passing it a `list` instead; you should do something like `root = Treenode()` and then `x.post_order_traversal_iterative(root)`
- once again since you put on the stack the `left` and `right` values of the current node they too should be instances of `Treenode`, not `integer`
- apart from being a `list` and not a `Treenode` your `root` contains four elements while three are requested

So assuming you were trying to create a mini tree with just a root node "1" with two children "2" and "3" you should have something like

```
rootnode = Treenode(val=1)
firstchild = Treenode(val=2)
secondchild = Treenode(val=3)
rootnode.left = firstchild
rootnode.right = secondchild
```

or more succinctly

```
rootnode = Treenode(val=1, left=Treenode(val=2), right=Treenode(val=3))
```

Comment: Thanks Gimix, I understand most of it now. To your second point, would I need to write all of this out: rootnode = Treenode(val=1)
firstchild = Treenode(val=2)
secondchild = Treenode(val=3)
rootnode.left = firstchild
rootnode.right = secondchild ???

Comment: Can't I organise it so the values just sit in the list? That seems a lot clearer/more efficient than writing all of it out like you have- what if I have 100 inputs???

Comment: To your last point- where in the code does it ask for three elements instead of 4?

Comment: The `__init__` method accepts 3 values (apart from `self` which is the object itself)

Comment: My example was just meant to let you see how the tree was going to be organized. When you have a real tree with many nodes I suppose you will be getting the data from some source, and you will define a function to build the tree